# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel awesome_notifications)

Tags: flutter, awesome-notifications

i already initialized awesome_notifications plugin in main.dart When i hot restart, in debug console i'm getting this error:

```
    E/flutter ( 4447): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel awesome_notifications)
E/flutter ( 4447): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:165
E/flutter ( 4447): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4447): #1      AwesomeNotifications.initialize (package:awesome_notifications/src/awesome_notifications_core.dart:174:18)
E/flutter ( 4447): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4447):
E/flutter ( 4447): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method isNotificationAllowed on channel awesome_notifications)
E/flutter ( 4447): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:165
E/flutter ( 4447): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Here's my code :

**main.dart**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(AddEventModelAdapter().typeId)) {
    Hive.registerAdapter(AddEventModelAdapter());
  }
  AwesomeNotifications()
      .initialize('resource://drawable/res_notification_app_icon', [
    NotificationChannel(
      channelKey: 'schedule_channel',
      channelName: 'scheduled_channel',
      channelDescription: 'descroiption',
      locked: true,
      importance: NotificationImportance.High,
    ),
  ]);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whenever you add a plugin in your pubspec.yaml, you need to **stop the app and re-run** it again because the plugin contains native code on both platforms.

If it still does not work, then do flutter clean and run.